# Vertical Table in LWC - Issue with returning RowWrappers from Apex

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, html

I'm trying to create this in LWC. It's a vertical table.
[image]

In Apex, I'd like to return a List of Rows. Example:
{Vendor Name, Company1, Company2, Company3},
{Quote Name, Company1data, Company2data, Company3data},
...

Then, in HTML, I can iterate Rows, and inner-iterate companyData along with HTML elements: tr and td.

But I can't get my Apex to work yet. The problem lies in:
data.value = quote.fieldsIndex[fieldsIndexIterator];

I've looked into iterating fields in SObject; it seems to require a cpu expensive workaround.

```
@AuraEnabled
public static List<Custom_Quote__c> getSelectedQuotes(String[] quoteIdsArray) {
    List<RowWrapper> rowList = new List<RowWrapper>();
    List<String> fields = new List<String>{'Vendor', 'Quote', 'Status', 'Purchase Agreement' };
    List<String> fieldsIndex = new List<String>{'Vendor_Name__c', 'Name', 'Status__c', 'Purchase_Agreement__r.Name' };

    List<Custom_Quote__c> selectedQuotes = [SELECT Vendor_Name__c, Name, Status__c, Purchase_Agreement__r.Name
                                          FROM Custom_Quote__c
                                          WHERE Id IN :quoteIdsArray];

   for (String field : fields) {
        RowWrapper row = new RowWrapper();
        row.fieldName = field;
        Integer fieldsIndexIterator = 0;
        for (Custom_Quote__c quote : selectedQuotes) {
            CompanyDataItem data = new CompanyDataItem();
            data.value = quote.fieldsIndex[fieldsIndexIterator];
            row.companiesDataList.add(data);
        }
        fieldsIndexIterator ++;
        rowList.add(row);
    }

    System.debug('*** selectedQuotes: ' + selectedQuotes);
    return selectedQuotes;
}

private class RowWrapper {
    @AuraEnabled public String fieldName { get; set;}
    @AuraEnabled public List<companyDataItem> companiesDataList;
}

private class CompanyDataItem {
    @AuraEnabled public String value;
}
```

Comment: `i` should be `fieldsIndexIterator`, but I don't see any other major issues here.

Comment: @sfdcfox You'll see my solution below. I would have preferred to do it as such in my original post. Are you saying that quote.fieldsIndex[fieldsIndexIterator]; would effectively get the Field API Name from fieldsIndex?

Comment: @sfdcfox Is returning a RowWrapper to LWC for iteration the best way to create the Vertical Table I'm trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

I added this if, else if logic and it works now.

```
@AuraEnabled
public static List<RowWrapper> getVerticalTableRows(String[] quoteIdsArray) {
    List<RowWrapper> rowList = new List<RowWrapper>();
    List<String> fields = new List<String>{'Vendor', 'Quote', 'Status', 'Purchase Agreement' };
    List<C_Quote__c> selectedQuotes = [SELECT Vendor_Name__c, Name, Status__c, Purchase_Agreement__r.Name
                                          FROM C_Quote__c
                                          WHERE Id IN :quoteIdsArray];
    // Row
    for (String field : fields) {
        RowWrapper row = new RowWrapper();
        row.companiesDataList = new List<CompanyDataItem>();
        row.fieldName = field;
        Integer i = 0;
        System.debug('*** row: ' + row);

        // Data
        for (C_Quote__c quote : selectedQuotes) {
            System.debug('*** quote: ' + quote);

            CompanyDataItem data = new CompanyDataItem();
            System.debug('*** data: ' + data);

            if(i==0) {
                data.value = quote.Vendor_Name__c;
                System.debug('*** i==0 data: ' + data);

            } else if(i==1) {
                data.value = quote.Name;
            }
            else if(i==2) {
                data.value = quote.Status__c;
            }
            else if(i==3) {
                data.value = quote.Purchase_Agreement__r.Name;
            }
            System.debug('*** row.companiesDataList: ' + row.companiesDataList);
            
            row.companiesDataList.add(data);
        }
        i++;
        rowList.add(row);
    }
```